# Mixing different Models on one Route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

We are using Ember together with Ember-Data and are stumped by following setup:

There is a parent object (`Epic`) which has a number of children (`UserStory`). We have modelled this accordingly using ember-data:

```js
App.Epic = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    description: DS.attr("string"),
    project: DS.belongsTo("App.Project")
});

App.UserStory = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    description: DS.attr("string"),
    goal: DS.attr("string"),
    benefit: DS.attr("string"),
    epic: DS.belongsTo("App.Epic")
});
```

What we would like to achieve now, is that we a have a list of independent forms to edit the `Epic` inline with all of its `UserStories`. Obvisouly we would simply deliver all of the `UserStories` together with the `Epic` via the `RESTAdapter`. Yet we are afraid that this would lead to ugly update scenarios: changing one `UserStory` would trigger a update of the entire `Epic` with all of its `UserStories`. In our architecture a `UserStory` is an indepenent entity which should be maintained by a dedidacted REST service.

As an ember-newbie we would like to implement something in the lines of:

- Load the `Epic` via ember-data
- Extend the `EpicController` to load all `UserStories` into a separate model-(list).
- Changes to the `Epic` via the dedicated form fire a change to the `Epic Rest Service`.
- *Magic:* Changes to an individual `UserStory` form fire an isolated and individual change to the `User Story Rest Service`.

How can the magic be achieved?

Comment: This seems to be the prime use case for side-loading, i.e. delivering the set of UserStories in the same API call as the Epic, but as a separate array instead of nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is kind of embarrassing, but what I wanted is exactly how ember-data behaves per default. All I needed to do, was to have the `Epic` REST-Service deliver the `UserStory` ids instead of the inline objects. Ember will get all children in one go - the URL setup is a bit ugly but works - and will use the `UserStory` rest-service to do the puts.

Ember has a steep but satisfying learning curve.

Thanks for your feedback.

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the controllerFor method:

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/